# python sqlite3 can't execute a valid sqlite3 command

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a feeling that this will be obvious but when I run a command in sqlite3 it's fine but then I run the same command from python sqlite3 it doesn't work.

Schema:

```
sqlite> .schema transcriptionUnit
CREATE TABLE "transcriptionUnit" (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Python function:

```
def getValue(path2db, tableName, columnName, findColumn, findValue):
    import sqlite3
    db = sqlite3.connect(path2db)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT '+columnName+' FROM '+tableName+' WHERE '+findColumn+' = '+findValue
    print(query)
    cursor.execute(query)
    all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
    db.close()

    return all_rows
```

Command in sqlite3:

```
sqlite> select id from transcriptionUnit where name = 'TU_001';
1
```

Command in ipython:

```
In [13]: db_funcs.getValue('/home/oli/Dropbox/Documents/PhD/wc-model-docs/geneLabels/gene_db/gene_db.db','transcriptionUnit', 'id', 'name', 'TU_001')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1797c506d95e> in <module>()
----> 1 db_funcs.getValue('/home/oli/Dropbox/Documents/PhD/wc-model-docs/geneLabels/gene_db/gene_db.db','transcriptionUnit', 'id', 'name', 'TU_001')

/home/oli/Dropbox/Documents/PhD/wc-model-docs/geneLabels/gene_db/python/read_db_funcs.pyc in getValue(path2db, tableName, columnName, findColumn, findValue)
 19         cursor = db.cursor()
 20         query = 'SELECT '+columnName+' FROM '+tableName+' WHERE '+findColumn+' = '+findValue
---> 21         cursor.execute(query)
 22         all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
 23         db.close()

OperationalError: no such column: TU_001
```

Just to show that the function generally works:

```
In [15]: db_funcs.getValue('/home/oli/Dropbox/Documents/PhD/wc-model-docs/geneLabels/gene_db/gene_db.db','transcriptionUnit', 'name', 'id', str(1))
Out[15]: [(u'TU_001',)]
```

My brain is now fried thinking about this so long so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Put the `findValue` in quotes. Otherwise Sqlite3 will consider it as a column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, strings must be quoted. You did this with the command in `sqlite3`, but not when constructing the command in Python.

But to avoid string formatting problems like this (and SQL injection attacks), better use parameters (which work only for values, not for table/column names):

```
query = 'SELECT '+columnName+' FROM '+tableName+' WHERE '+findColumn+' = ?'
cursor.execute(query, [findValue])
```

Comment: Hi CL., thanks for your solution, it worked but I still don't understand why mine didn't work. Would you mind explaining since findValue='TU_001' which is quoted so why does sqlite3 not see it as quoted?

Comment: Your `query` string does not contain quotes.